# Entity Framework 6 expression modification

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, expression, iqueryable

I would like to remove the where clause from the expression of IQueryable. Can I do that, please?
There is an extension method what takes an IQueryable as a parameter. This IQueryable contains where clause. I want to query the total number of rows without filtering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where clauses inside query expression trees are represented as a calls to the [`Queryable.Where(source, predicate)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2) extension method.

Hence you can use custom [ExpressionVisitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor?view=netframework-4.7.2) to locate them and remove by returning the first argument (which is the `source`) like this:

```
public static class QueryableUtils
{
    public static IQueryable<T> RemoveWhere<T>(this IQueryable<T> source)
    {
        var expression = new WhereRemover().Visit(source.Expression);
        if (expression == source.Expression) return source;
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(expression);
    }

    class WhereRemover : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
        {
            // Queryable.Where(source, predicate)
            if (node.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(Queryable) && node.Method.Name == "Where")
                return base.Visit(node.Arguments[0]); // source
            return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this will remove all `Queryable.Where` calls, so use with care.